# Service worker install event firing before each fetch when no changes to the service worker are made

Tags: javascript, service-worker, service-worker-events

According to service worker documentation, the install event should only fire once per service worker; however, if I put a console.log inside of the install event listener, I am noticing that before a fetch occurs, the install event is always fired.

Why is the install event for the service worker getting called even when there have been no changes/updates to the SW.  Does the service worker's install event get called if it goes idle for a short period of time?  This is a problem as the caching is done during install, and if the install event gets called before the fetch occurs, we are updating the cache constantly when it doesn't need to be updated at all.

Thanks for the help!

```
const CACHE_NAME = 'my-cache-v2';
const cacheAllowList = [CACHE_NAME];
const externalFiles = [
    various files here
];


self.addEventListener('fetch', function (event) {
    event.respondWith(
        self.caches
            .match(event.request)
            .then(function (response) {
                if (response) {
                    return response;
                }
                return fetch(event.request);
            })
    );
});

self.addEventListener('install', function (event) {
    // Perform install steps
    event.waitUntil(
        self.caches.keys().then(function (cacheNames) {
                // Add cache
                self.caches.open(CACHE_NAME).then((cache) => {
                    return cache.addAll([
                        ...externalFiles
                    ]);
                })
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.log('Service worker cache failed: ' + error);
                    })
        })
    );
});


self.addEventListener('activate', function (event) {

    // All caches not listed here will be deleted.

    event.waitUntil(
        self.caches.keys().then(function (cacheNames) {
            return Promise.all(
                cacheNames.map(function (cacheName) {
                    if (cacheAllowList.indexOf(cacheName) === -1) {
                        return self.caches.delete(cacheName);
                    }
                })
            );
        })
    );
});

self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {
    console.log('[Service Worker] Push Received.');
    console.log(`[Service Worker] Push had this data: "${event.data.text()}"`);

    const title = 'Push Codelab';
    const options = {
        body: 'Push notifications',
        icon: 'images/icon.png',
        badge: 'images/badge.png'
    };

    event.waitUntil(self.registration.showNotification(title, options));
});
```

*Edit - Its important to note that this doesn't always happen.  Sometimes the fetch works fine without calling install, other times install gets called for seemly no reason before the fetch occurs.

Comment: Install event is only fired when we register service worker not after that. Can you please share your service worker code? It would be more helpful if you can share your app url.

Comment: @VimalPatel it has been added.  I removed the list of files, but it is just a list of js files.

Comment: Does not looks like code issue at all. However as you have mentioned, its an intermittent issues, so difficult to answer without debugging it.